# No Viable Overloaded +=?

Tags: c++, vector, overloading

Can somebody please enlighten me as to why I'm receiving this "No viable overloaded"? I'm confused as to why i'm receiving this.... I'm a rookie.

```
int main()
{
char ch;
    vector<int> temp;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("tempsF.txt");

    if (infile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Could not open file numbers." << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    int data;
    infile >> data;
    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        if(isalpha(ch) || ispunct(ch))
        {
            if(isupper(ch) && ch != '\n')

                temp += " ";<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< No Viable Overloaded '+='

                temp += ch;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< No Viable Overloaded '+='
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you even expect adding a string literal to a vector of ints to do?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You are doing `+=` with operands of type `vector<int>` and `char[2]`.  There is no overload of `operator+=` for those operand types, hence the error message.

Answer (score 7):

That's *not* how you use a `std::vector<int>`.  Try something more like:

```
temp.push_back(42);
```

or maybe you want a `std::vector<std::string>` then you can:

```
temp.push_back(" ");
```

but there's no `operator +=()` defined for `std::vector`.